# Minimum of two different probability density functions

Tags: probability

I have two random variables: one following an exponential distribution and one following a gaussian distribution. I would like to know what is the minimum of these two variables PDF. I really have no clue on what to do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but you don't want the "mininum of two density functions" but the minimum of two random variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't assume that the variables are independent you cannot find the distribution of their minimum. Assuming independence you can use the following: $P(\min \{X,Y\}>x)=P(X>x,Y>x)=P(X>x)P(Y>x)$ so $P(\min \{X,Y\}\leq x)=1-P(X>x)P(Y>x)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Does it work the same for the max?

Comment: For max it is simpler: $P(\max \{X,Y\} \leq x)=P(X\leq x, Y\leq x)=P(X\leq x) P(Y\leq x)$.

Comment: But $P(X \leq x)$ is the CDF of the function, not its PDF right?

Comment: PDF is simply the derivative of CDF. I have left it to you to calculate CDF and then differentiate it.